# MpMoviePlayerViewController closed after setContentURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I make mpmovieplayerviewcontroller and load movie in it (from stream). Now I have call to setContentURL method that change URL and it works. Whenn app is first time started it shows view with button after button is pressed it opens movie player and load movie. But when I call code where is setContentURL player close it self first, go back to first view where I have to again click play button to again open player (so it remembers and load new URL). How to prevent player to not close it self when switching URL? This must be some small issue, please help :)
This is code when play button is clicked (first view)

```
-(void)initializeMovieFromStream:(NSString *)var
{
    if(player != nil)
    {
        NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://"];
        NSURL *nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:title];
        NSLog(@"Switching channel...");
        [player.moviePlayer setContentURL:nurl];    
        isMoviePaused = NO;
    }
    else
    {       
        NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"http://"];
        NSURL *nurl = [NSURL URLWithString:title];

        player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:nurl];
        [player.moviePlayer.view.window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;



    }   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedPlaying:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:[player moviePlayer]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(nowPlayingMovieDidChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
    //[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

    UIView *mv = player.view;
    //[mv setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [mv addSubview:myOverlayChannelPicker];
    [mv bringSubviewToFront:myOverlayChannelPicker];

    // register this class to observe TestNotification that comes from OverlayChannelPicker
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveTestNotification:) 
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(pauseStreamNotificationHandler:) 
                                                 name:@"notiPauseStream"
                                               object:nil];

}

-(void) movieFinishedPlaying: (NSNotification *)note
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:[player moviePlayer]];

    //[player release]; 
}
```

When URL need to be switch I use this nitification handler

```
- (void) receiveTestNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{   
    NSString *stringFromNote = (NSString *)[notification object];
    [switchableChannel setString:stringFromNote];
    [self initializeMovieFromStream:stringFromNote];        
}
```

It is solved I just change animation property to NO.

Comment: Now I find out that if I put [self presentModalViewController:player animated:NO]; (NO instead YES for animation), player window is not closed, but sometimes it loads new URL sometimes no (show only blank white screen)...o so close and again so far :(

Comment: Now you can play multiple movie or video files together in iphone check this link for nice tutorial http://cocoabugs.blogspot.com/2010/12/playing-movies-or-videos-in-queue-using.html

Comment: Having the same issue that if I call setContentURL on MPMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer the ViewController hides. Does anybody have a solution?